# changing all css selectors on page with js

Tags: javascript, css, google-tag-manager

im trying to use a dom event trigger using tag manager to run a script that will change all the on page elements with the same css selector

this is the JS loop im trying to run :

```
<script>
     function dissapper() {
   var e = document.getElementsByClassName('form-disappear');
    for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
        e[i].style.display="none";
    }
}
  function appear() {
   var e = document.getElementsByClassName('form_appear');
    for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
        e[i].style.display="block";
    }
}

</script>
```

any idea why its not working ?

Comment: Where and when are `dissapper()` and `appear()` called?

Comment: Please click edit, then the `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a [mcve]

Comment: hi @NullDev - thank you so much. add a function call at the end.

Answer (score 0):

so al i needed to fix this was to add a function call at the end like so :

```
<script>
     function dissapper() {
   var e = document.getElementsByClassName('form-disappear');
    for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
        e[i].style.display="none";
    }
}
  function appear() {
   var e = document.getElementsByClassName('form_appear');
    for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
        e[i].style.display="block";
    }
}
dissapper()
appear()
</script>
```

thank you @nulldev for pointing it out.